# How to get modified date as column in table while ingesting all files from year/month/date directories of storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have some json files in ADLS account. The files are ingested in multiple Year/Month/Day directory structure. I want to copy all the files from ADLS to Azure SQL DB using azure data flow.
I am able to ingest the data from using data flow but I want to include the file path, file ingestion date along with the file name in three separate columns but I do not know how to get these values.

**Please note that each Day directory has more than one file as following:**

`container_name/Dataset/Year/Month/Day/file1.json.file2.json,file3.json`

Could any one help me , how do I ingest the modified date column in table with data of each files

tried using getmedata to copy each file on by one also in dataflow derived column for any modified date

Comment: Do you want the last modified date of files or the date should be from the parent folder names? can you clarify this?

Comment: Hi @RakeshGovindula  , I need last modified date of files which having the timestamp too

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and able to get the desired file by using combination of **addional column option in copy activity**, **lookup** and **Get Meta data activity**.

In this these are my datasets which I have used at various activities with dataset parameters.

**Source_files_wild_path:**

[image]

**temporary_filepaths:**

[image]

**Each_file:**

[image]

**intermediate:**

[image]

**target_folder:**

[image]

**AFAIK**, in ADF we can get the last modified date of files either by **REST APIs or Get Meta data**. But Get Meta data won't work with dynamic file paths with a folder structure like yours.

Also, we can get the file path of a blob file either **from triggers or additonal column option of copy activity only**. Here, as there is no usage of triggers, I have used the 2nd method.

- So, First I have used a **copy activity** with wild card path to all source files and added **`$$FILEPATH`** as column and copied to a temporary file `temp1.csv` with `Merge files` as copy behavior.
- Then I have used a **lookup activity** to `temp1.csv` to get the file as array of objects by which I can get the file paths list.
- Here I have created two variables of array type.

  [image]
- As it is lookup output is an array objects, to get only the `filename` object array, use a for loop and append the `@item().filepath` to `path_list` array.
- Then use the below expression to get the unique list of all file paths in `unique_path_list` array.

  `@union(variables('path_list'),variables('path_list'))`
- Now, use this array in a ForEach and inside **Foreach**, use a **Get Meta data activity** with `each_file` dataset and `@item()` as filename and add the **filedsList** like `Item name` and `Last modified`.
- Then use **copy activity** inside Foreach, and use the same dataset. Here add the additional columns like filename, filepath and last modified and give those values.
- In sink of this copy activity use another temporary folder and staging(dataset `intermediate`). give random file name using date function.
- After ForEach, use another copy activity with **`intermediate` dataset as source**(use wild card path `*.csv` and give any empty string to dataset parameter) and `target_folder` folder as sink to get the result file by using merge files.

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
"name": "last_modifed_pipeline_copy1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "for_paths_columns",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "additionalColumns": [
                        {
                            "name": "filepath",
                            "value": "$$FILEPATH"
                        }
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFolderPath": "*/*/*",
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true,
                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "Source_files_wild_card_path",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "temporary_filepaths",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Lookup1",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "for_paths_columns",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "temporary_filepaths",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "append filepaths array",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "path_list",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item().filepath",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "get_unique_paths array",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "append filepaths array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "unique_path_list",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@union(variables('path_list'),variables('path_list'))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "adds_last modifed column",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "get_unique_paths array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('unique_path_list')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Get Metadata1",
                        "type": "GetMetadata",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "dataset": {
                                "referenceName": "Each_file",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "filename": {
                                        "value": "@item()",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "fieldList": [
                                "itemName",
                                "lastModified"
                            ],
                            "storeSettings": {
                                "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                            },
                            "formatSettings": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Copy data2",
                        "type": "Copy",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "policy": {
                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                            "retry": 0,
                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                            "secureOutput": false,
                            "secureInput": false
                        },
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                "additionalColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "file_path",
                                        "value": "$$FILEPATH"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "file_name",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "last_modifed",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "recursive": true,
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            },
                            "sink": {
                                "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                    "quoteAllText": true,
                                    "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                }
                            },
                            "enableStaging": false,
                            "translator": {
                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                "typeConversion": true,
                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "Each_file",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "filename": {
                                        "value": "@item()",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "referenceName": "intermediate",
                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "file_name": {
                                        "value": "@concat(utcNow(),'.csv')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Copy data3",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "adds_last modifed column",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFileName": "*.csv",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": "MergeFiles"
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true,
                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "intermediate",
                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                    "parameters": {
                        "file_name": "No value"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "target_folder",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "path_list": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "unique_path_list": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "lastPublishTime": "2023-01-27T12:40:51Z"
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

**My pipeline:**

[image]

**Result file:**

[image]

***NOTE:***

If you want run this on a regular basis, use Storage event trigger by which you can use trigger parameters like `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName`. you can give these to Get Meta data to get last modified time and then pass it to copy activity or dataflow to add as additonal column as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Govindula, thanks for your response. I tried that pipeline but getting the following error in lookup activity-" The size of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation 4194304" .I have more than 15000 rows in my data. could you please suggest the solution to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, lookup has the limitation of only 5000 rows, so instead of lookup, For Each and set variable activities, use dataflow and use `temporary_filepaths` dataset as source for it. inside dataflow use derived column and union dataflow expression to get unique file paths column. after that use select transformation to select only that column. then use sink cache to get the array of objects. Modify or use this file paths array as per your requirement.